# ComboBox loop with if then

Tags: vb.net

I need to loop the following code 12 times:

```
If t3frm.ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then t3t1 = Val(t3frm.TextBox1.Text)
If t3frm.ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then t3t1 = Val(t3frm.TextBox1.Text) * m
If t3frm.ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 2 Then t3t1 = Val(t3frm.TextBox1.Text) * b
If t3frm.ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 3 Then t3t1 = Val(t3frm.TextBox1.Text) * t
If t3frm.ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 4 Then t3t1 = Val(t3frm.TextBox1.Text) * kt
If t3frm.ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 5 Then t3t1 = Val(t3frm.TextBox1.Text) * mt
If t3frm.ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 6 Then t3t1 = Val(t3frm.TextBox1.Text) * bt
If t3frm.ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 7 Then t3t1 = Val(t3frm.TextBox1.Text) * tt
```

I have 12 comboboxes (1-12), 12 variables (t3t1-t3t12) and 12 textboxes (1-12).

So each of these will need to increase by 1.

How can I do this please?

Comment: I think you can't dynamically call a variable by its name, so you will need to copy this code 12 times
Or you can use dictionary so the Key should be your ComboBox and the value should be your the t3t variables ( you won't have the variables in this case, you will get or set those values from dictionary based on ComboBox )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a control by name from the `Controls` collection.

Instead of having individual variables `t3t1, t3 t2, t3t3 ...`, use an array

```
Dim t3t(12) As Double

For i As Integer = 1 To 12
    Dim cb = DirectCast(t3frm.Controls("ComboBox" & i), ComboBox)
    Dim tb = DirectCast(t3frm.Controls("TextBox1" & i), TextBox)

    Select Case cb.SelectedIndex
        Case 0
            t3t(i) = Val(tb.Text)
        Case 1
            t3t(i) = Val(tb.Text) * m
        Case 2
            t3t(i) = Val(tb.Text) * b
        Case 3
            t3t(i) = Val(tb.Text) * t
        Case 4
            t3t(i) = Val(tb.Text) * kt
        Case 5
            t3t(i) = Val(tb.Text) * mt
        Case 6
            t3t(i) = Val(tb.Text) * bt
        Case 7
            t3t(i) = Val(tb.Text) * tt
    End Select
Next
```

If you store the value 1 and the variables `m` to `tt` in an array, you can simplify the code further

```
Dim factor = {1, m, b, t, kt, mt, bt, tt}
Dim t3t(12) As Double

For i As Integer = 1 To 12
    Dim cb = DirectCast(t3frm.Controls("ComboBox" & i), ComboBox)
    Dim tb = DirectCast(t3frm.Controls("TextBox1" & i), TextBox)
    t3t(i) = Val(tb.Text) * factor(cb.SelectedIndex)
Next
```

See: [Arrays in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/)

Comment: Did you mean `$"ComboBox{i}"` or `"ComboBox" & i.ToString()` instead of  `"ComboBox" & i`? Also, I suggest `Double.TryParse` instead of `Val` - the latter may be too loose in what it accepts as a number.

Comment: In `"ComboBox" & i` VB automatically converts `i` to a string. Yes, TryParse with some error handling is always a good idea.

Comment: I think that here it is the string concatenation itself that does the conversion. See: [& Operator (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/concatenation-operator). The Remarks say: "If the data type of expression1 or expression2 is not String but widens to String, it is converted to String.". Therefore the Option Strict has no effect here. See also : https://dotnetfiddle.net/mDyU33

Comment: Yes, that is a good point. It's just that it never *looks* right to me.

Comment: Note that even `Option Strict On` allows implicit widening coversions e.g. from `Integer` to `Double`. See [Option Explicit and Option Strict in Visual Basic .NET and in Visual Basic](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/311329/option-explicit-and-option-strict-in-visual-basic--net-and-in-visual-b).

Answer (score 0):

> I have 12 comboboxes (1-12), 12 variables (t3t1-t3t12) and 12
>   textboxes (1-12).

Seems like perfect candidate for collection which can be bounded to the `DataGridView` control.
Create a class which will represent your data

```
Public Class Item Implement INotifyPropertyChanged
    Private _Value As Decimal
    Public Property Value As Decimal
        Get
            Return _Value
        End Property
        Set
            _Value = value
            RaisePropertyChanged(NameOf(Result)) // Notify control to update result
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _Factor As Decimal        
    Public Property Factor As Decimal
        Get
            Return _Factor
        End Property
        Set
            _Factor = value
            RaisePropertyChanged(NameOf(Result)) // Notify control to update result
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Result As Decimal

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Private Sub RaisePropertyChanged(<CallerMemberName()> Optional propertyName As String = Nothing)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub
End Class
```

Create `DataGridView` with predefined columns in constructor (you can do it in designer too)

```
Dim factor = {1, m, b, t, kt, mt, bt, tt}
Dim valueColumn = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn With
{
    .DataPropertyName = "Value" ' Name of the correspondent property in Item class
}
Dim resultColumn = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn With
{
    .DataPropertyName = "Result",
    .ReadOnly = True
}
Dim factorColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
{
    .DataPropertyName = "Factor",
    .DataSource = factors; // will add factors to combobox items
}

yourDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = False // Will use only columns you created
yourDataGridView.Columns.Add(valueColumn)
yourDataGridView.Columns.Add(factorColumn)
yourDataGridView.Columns.Add(factorColumn)

' Create collection of 12 items and bind it to DataGridView

Dim items = Enumerable.Range(0, 12).Select(Function(i) New Item())
Dim source = new BindingList(Of Item)(items)
yourDataGridView.DataSource = source;
```

With approach above, DataGridView will show 12 textboxes, 12 comboBoxes and 12 textboxes with result of selections. When you change selection of combobox or update value in DataGridView cell, `Result` property will be updated

You will be able access results in the code if you make `items` variable a member of your form or some other class, so you will get access to it from places you need.